# Access of the data by the server on the server machine

Tags: language-agnostic

My question is I know that a server application can access the data stored at server but cannot access teh data stored at client machine as this is a security issue and Browsers not allow this. But in case of localHost (when my local pc is acting as a server) I should be able to access the files from my PC(the local PC on which the application is running). But that is not happening.
Why i m not able to access a simple image file form my local C:\ drive by localhost. The URL i used was file:///c:/image.png but if i store this image any where under home directory of tomcat i m able to access it. WHY ?? 
I m using it as <'img src="file:///c:/image.png>
Thanks for any considerations..

Comment: What browser are you on? Some have security restrictions to disallow this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this part:

> The URL i used was file:///c:/image.png but if i store this image any
>   where under home directory of tomcat i m able to access it.

If you want to access the file through Tomcat after placing it in Tomcat's document-root, then the URL to use (assuming you haven't changed the default port setting) is:

`http://localhost:8080/image.png`

Content hosted by the web-server needs to be accessed through the web-server.  A `file://` URL bypasses any sort of server, and basically directs the browser to look directly in the local filesystem.  So it should also work if you were to do:

`file:///C:/path/to/tomcat/home/image.png`

But in that case you are *not* going through Tomcat.  You're just pointing the browser at the tomcat folder in your local filesystem.

Edit:  I don't think many browsers will not allow `file://` urls in tags in hosted documents.  Doing so could cause the appearance of a security hole, as if you could guess the name of an image file on someone's local filesystem you could then post a webpage that made it appear as if your server had somehow grabbed their personal image file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer but my question is if the file is in local filesystem and not in tomcat directory the why i m not ble to access it by using file:///c:/image.png as u said that this should go file:///C:/path/to/tomcat/home/image.png so this should also work file:///c:/image.png but its not !!!

Comment: Okay, I revised my answer.  The problem is that you're putting a `file://` url into an `img` tag.  I wouldn't expect that to work.